# android - could not get location coordinates

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps

This is my code for getting gps coordinates.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                getPermissions();
            } else
                doGPS();
private void getPermissions() {
        int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        } else
            doGPS();
    }

    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (permsRequestCode == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            getPermissions();
        }
    }
public void doGPS() {

        try {
            mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                mlocListener = new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        getCordinate(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                    }
                };
                mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
            }
    }
```

It first checks for permission and when It granted them , call for `getGps`

I've this code in my manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

It takes for ever to call the method `getCordinate` , it doesn't come to `onLocationChanged` at all.

I've checked other apps like google map and it get the coordinates correctly.

### what is wrong with it  ?

update 1:
there is something strange , when I'm in a place without anymove , it doesn't work but when I start moving around , it works, how can I force it to get the coordinate while I'm not moving ?

Comment: use android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION to get exact co-ordinates.

Comment: @AshishJohn thanks for reply but I've this permission in my code

Comment: Use Fused Location api it is very good api it give acurate result.